# Change the format of date column from integer to date time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

My dataframe's `date` column looks like this and contains integers:
[image]

I want to convert the `date` column (now containing dtype integers) into `%Y%m%d` format so that the first row looks like `2002-01-01`.

After using the following code:

`party_dataset['date'] = party_dataset['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))`

the column values start to like this  `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002002, 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002003`... (the actual year being sent to the very end).

Can somebody please suggest an example solution code?

Comment: `party_dataset['date'] = pd.to_datetime(party_dataset['date'], format='%Y')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This this is the answer

```
import datetime
s = "20120213"
s_datetime = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m%d')).split(' ')[0]
print(s_datetime)
```

another way to get the result

```
from datetime import datetime
a = '20160228'
print(datetime.strptime(a, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```